# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 2860: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, json

I have the following record from JSON file that is giving me the error-

> {"categoryId":"mpc-pc-optimization",
>   "categoryName":"PC Optimization",
>   "productMap":
>       {"mpp-aol-computer-checkup":"AOL Computer Checkup®",
>       "mpp-assist-by-aol-free-scan":"Assist by AOL Free Scan",
>       "mpp-mybenefits":"Monthly Statement of Benefits",
>       "mpp-perfectspeed":"PerfectSpeed",
>       "mpp-system-checkup":"***System Checkup™***","mpp-system-mechanic":"System Mechanic®"}}

The highlighted portion is causing the error.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from that ™ (trademark symbol), which is not part of the ascii code.
The byte 0xe2 is 11100010 in binary, which is outside the range of 128 (01111111 in binary).

The problem is that you are trying to decode with ascii, and instead should decode with unicode (e.g. UTF-8).

You could use a try-catch-block to catch the exception and then handle it by decoding as UTF-8.

```
try:
    unicode(my_json_string, "ascii")
except UnicodeError:
    value = unicode(my_json_string, "utf-8")
```

Comment: By the way: by saying the range of 128, I refered to the error message saying "not in range(128)", which actually means the numbers from 0 to 127, the 128 being the first number out of range.

Comment: According to the [JSON spec](http://json.org/), a *string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters*. So decoding it as ascii is not the right way (although it will probably often work). You should probably try with the different unicode encodings.